# can`t get value from session Online using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The `Session::get('session_var')` don`t work online (on a production server). Offline i can get the value from it.

I use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session` in laravel 5.4

I do some operation in controller and i am using `Session::put('session_var', value)` to store some values.

When it redirect me to the view i want to check that 'session_var' if it`s there using blade

```
if: @if(Session::get('session_var'))
```

On my local server is there. The problem is online that is not there. In storage/sessions i can see the sessions and my variables that i set it are there.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Dont you get any error when using Session ?

Comment: No. I don't see any error in storage/logs from today

Comment: I made some test ONLINE...if i set the session in the controller constructor, i get it on the view. I am using socialite for google+ login. Setting the session variables in that function `handleProviderCallback($provider)`, when google redirect me back to the view can`t access the variables in the session (like the session is empty). BUT on localhost there is no such thing - it works fine!

Comment: Did you change chmod for storage directory on server?

Comment: Same problem here , unable to  access old session values inside `handleProviderCallback` after successful fb login and redirect . Read @calin24 's comment added  domain in session.php and in .env. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem....in the .env file i was having SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

I forgot to modify it to the name of the domain or delete the line to use the default